# Extension of a differentiable function $f$ to an open superset

Tags: calculus, analysis, functions, derivatives

This is a question the book Munkres-Calculus on Manifolds pg.144(Exercise 3-b)
If $f :S\to \mathbb R$ and $f$ is differentiable of class $C^r$ at each point $x_0$ of $S$,then $f$ may be extended to a $C^r$ function $h: A\to \mathbb R$ that is defined on an open set $A$ of $\mathbb R^n$ containing $S$.

My attempt, with $f:S \to \mathbb R$ is $C^r$, for each $x \in S$,then for each $x \in S$,
I can choose $U_x$ open neighborhood of $x$ such that $\cup U_x = A$ open (arbitrary union of abiertos es abierto).The item before "a"(pg.144.Exercise 3),it is show that if $f$ is $C^r$ then  always exists $g:U_x \to \mathbb R $ where $x \in U_x \subset \mathbb R^n$ such that $f$ is equal to $g$ when $U_x \cap S$ and

$$h(x) =\left \{ \begin{matrix} \phi(x)g(x)& \mbox{if }x\mbox{ $\in U_x$ }
\\ 0 & \mbox{if }x\mbox{ $\notin \operatorname{supp} \phi$}\end{matrix}\right. 
$$
Is $C^r$ with $\phi:\mathbb R^n  \to \mathbb R $ is $C^r$, where your support is in $U_x$.Choosing $h:A \to \mathbb R $ with the extension of $f$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a partition of unity: following your idea, we have by hypothesis, for each $s\in S$, opens $U_s\ni s$ and $C^r$ functions $\tilde f_s:U_s\to \mathbb R$ such that $\tilde f_s|_S=f.$ Choose $\{\psi_s:s\in S\}$ a smooth partition of unity subordinate to the cover $\{U_s:s\in S\}$ and set $\tilde f:U:=\bigcup_{s\in S} U_s\to \mathbb R:\ x\mapsto \sum _{s\in S}\psi_s(x)\tilde f_s(x)$. The sum is finite because $\{\text{supp}\ \psi_s:s\in S\}$ is locally finite. Now $S\subseteq U,\ U$ is open and $\tilde f$ is clearly $C^r$. Finally, if $x\in S,$ and $s\in S$ such that  $\psi_s(x)\neq 0,$ then $x\in U_s$ so $\tilde f_s(x)=f(x)$. It follows that $\tilde f(x)=\sum _{s\in S}\psi_s(x)\tilde f_s(x)=\sum _{s\in S}\psi_s(x) f(x)=f(x)\sum _{s\in S}\psi_s(x)=f(x)$ so $\tilde f$ agrees with $f$ on $S.$

Answer (score 0):

The author solves this exercise on p.199 (proof of Lemma 23.1).

> Lemma 23.1. Let $S$ be a subset of $\mathbb{R}^k$; let $f:S\to\mathbb{R}^n$. If for each $x\in S$, there is a neighborhood $U_x$ of $x$ and a function $g_x:U_x\to\mathbb{R}^n$ of class $C^r$ that agrees with $f$ on $U_x\cap S$, then $f$ is of class $C^r$ on $S$.

> Proof. The lemma was given as an exercise in $\S$16; we provide a proof here. Cover $S$ by the neighborhoods $U_x$; let $A$ be the union of these neighborhoods; let $\{\phi_i\}$ be a partition off unity on $A$ of class $C^r$ dominated by the collection $\{U_x\}$. For each $i$, choose one of the neighborhoods $U_x$ containing the support $\phi_i$, and let $g_i$ denote the $C^r$ function $g_x:U_x\to\mathbb{R}^n$. The $C^r$ function $\phi_ig_i:U_x\to\mathbb{R}^n$ vanishes outside a closed subset of $U_x$; we extend it to a $C^r$ function $h_i$ on all of $A$ by letting it vanish outside $U_x$. Then we define $$g(x)=\sum_{i=1}^\infty h_i(x)$$ for each $x\in A$. Each point of $A$ has a neighborhood on which $g$ equals a funite sum of functions $h_i$; thus $g$ is of class $C^r$ on this neighborhood and hence on all of $A$. Furthermore, if $x\in S$, then $$h_i(x)=\phi_i(x)g_i(x)=\phi_i(x)f(x)$$ for each $i$ for which $\phi_i(x)\neq 0$. Hence if $x\in S$, $$g(x)=\sum_{i=1}^\infty \phi_i(x)f(x)=f(x).$$

Comment: Thank you @佐武五郎